# Accessing database using C

Tags: mysql, c, database

I am working on a problem where I need to store and retrive the data from the database . I am using C for that on windows system . I am familiar with MYSQL database . I just need to know whether its possible for me to access database using C if yes which IDE I can use and how can I connect it to MYSQL .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can connect your C code to MySQL using a connector (driver) available on MySql home page: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

There is a nice tutorial on writing C programs accessing MySQL: [MySQL C API programming tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/)

You can use any IDE you want for writing your code, for example Visual Studio. Here you can download a free version: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express

Answer (score 7):

Yes, of course you can. You just need to download [MySQL libraries](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/). Here simple example of how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "mysql/mysql.h" 

int main() { 
    MYSQL mysql; 

    if(mysql_init(&mysql)==NULL) { 
        printf("\nInitialization error\n"); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","user","pass","dbname",0,NULL,0); 

    printf("Client version: %s",mysql_get_client_info()); 
    printf("\nServer version: %s",mysql_get_server_info(&mysql)); 
    mysql_close(&mysql); 
    return 1; 
}
```

You can use anyone IDE you want to. All you need is to set paths for include, lib and bin folders in MySQL.

Comment: I am trying to use codeblocks for it . Can you say me the procedure ?

Comment: The easiest way is to copy these three folders to folder where you have your compiler, which is mingw as i suppose

Answer (score 1):

I write a library in C++ for database access. With this library you can connect e retrieve data from postgresql, mysql and mysql.

You can get the code here: https://github.com/vitorluis/VSQL

And you can try out this library and share with other people.